# A calculation about strong derivative Nijenhuis' paper

Tags: analysis, derivatives

Picture below is from the 971th page of
*Nijenhuis, Albert*, [**Strong derivatives and inverse mappings**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2319298), Am. Math. Mon. 81, 969-980 (1974). [ZBL0296.58002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0296.58002).

I can't get the red line, I don't know why it is $(Df)_{x_1}$, since in (3) only at $x_0$, $f$  is strong derivative, but about the $x_1$ there is nothing be mentioned.

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you have not understood what's the difference between Frechet differential and strong derivative. The map $f$ in (3) is supposed to be Frechet differentiable in a neighbourhood of $x_0$, so $Df(x_1)$ exists at any point in a neighbourhood of $x_0$. For any $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that for any $x\in B(x_0,\delta)$ and $\lvert t\rvert< \delta-\lvert x-x_0\rvert$ we have:
$$\lVert Df(x)-l\rVert=\sup_{v\in B(0,1)}\Big\lvert (Df(x)-l)[v]\Big\rvert\\\leq \sup_{v\in B(0,1)} \frac{\Big\lvert f(x+tv)-f(x)-tDf(x)[v]\Big\rvert+\Big\lvert f(x+tv)-f(x)-tl[v]\Big\rvert}{t}\\
\leq \sup_{v\in B(0,1)}\frac{\Big\lvert f(x+tv)-f(x)-tDf(x)[v]\Big\rvert}{t}+\epsilon\leq \epsilon,$$
where the last inequality follows since $f$ is supposed Frechet differentiable at any $x\in B(x_0,\delta)$ and by the arbitrariness of $t$.